# Send progress from Asyncio loop to website

Tags: python, flask, server-sent-events, python-asyncio

I have a Python app with a Flask API that does some parallel work using asyncio. It takes a while to complete so every once in a while I'd like to report progress to the website, using server-sent events.

The best idea I've come up with (I know this is garbage and totally not thread-safe, but it's just an example):

```
import asyncio
from threading import Thread

counter = 0

def background_loop(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()

async def something(t):
    await asyncio.sleep(t)

async def generator():
    pending = [something(t) for t in range(0, 5)]
    while pending:
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(pending, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        for task in done:
            yield task.result()

async def consumer():
    global counter
    async for _ in generator():
        counter += 1

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
t = Thread(target=background_loop, args=(loop,), daemon=True)
t.start()

#here would be the endpoint
task = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(consumer(), loop)
while counter != 5:
    print(counter)
```

Are there any better ways to do this? Thanks!